# Linked Table Shows As read only

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, dao

I am using C# to create a SQL Server view, then open an access database and link the table into access.  The create view statement, open database statement and link statement work great *BUT* the catch here is it will always link the table as read-only.  What piece o'code do I need to add or update current so that the view is not always linked as read-only?

```
string MasterDatabase = "R:\\Testing\\MasterDatabase.mdb";
DAO.Database dd;
DAO.DBEngine db = new DAO.DBEngine();
DAO.TableDef tdf9;
bool found = false;
DAO.TableDef tdf1;
string Table = "ServiceEntranceLog";
string TableAccess = "Service_Entrance_Log";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringHere))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{   
            using (var command4 = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                            command4.CommandText = "CREATE VIEW HelperView" AS SELECT * FROM monster.ServiceEntranceLog";
                            command4.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
}
if (_combobox1.SelectedItems.Contains("MasterDatabase"))
{
            dd = db.OpenDatabase(CRDB);
            try
            {
                            string[] tableNames = new string[1] { TableAccess };
                            for (int q = tableNames.GetLowerBound(0); q <= tableNames.GetUpperBound(0); q++)
                            {
                                            foreach (DAO.TableDef tabledef in dd.TableDefs)
                                            {
                                                            string name = tableNames[q];
                                                            if (tabledef.Name == name) { found = true; }
                                                            try { if (found) { dd.TableDefs.Delete(name); } }
                                                            catch { }
                                            }
                            }
            }
            catch { }
            tdf1 = dd.CreateTableDef(TableAccess);
            tdf1.Connect = connectionString;
            tdf1.SourceTableName = Table;
            dd.TableDefs.Append(tdf1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alritey, so it seems the issue is I needed to define a primary key when linking in the table into access so that the table would be updateable.  Using this syntax does the trick

```
dd.Execute "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SomeIndex ON SomeTable (PrimaryKeyColumn) WITH PRIMARY"
```